# How do I wrap my web browser game as a standalone for Steam?

Tags: java, php, steam

I've got a PHP/Java based game, which runs in the browser. However, I want to submit this game to Steam.

Now Steam doesn't allow web-based games unless they come in some kind of wrapper.

How can I package my web broswer game so that I could distribute it through Steam?

Comment: PHP doesn't run in the browser, it's a purely server-based language.

Comment: Also, is it Java-based or JavaScript-based? The two aren't related. http://www.javascriptisnotjava.com

Comment: @Bálint it is java based, not javascript

Comment: @Bálint it might be possible to bundle a webserver with the game and run it locally. But that would of course only make sense when it's a singleplayer game.

Comment: You might read the OP’s comment on my answer Phillip @Bálint.  His game is server based.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention PHP as well as Java, which are both server-side languages, I assume you are running a web server that your game connects to for content, game state management, and so forth.

So given you have a web server, you'll want the player to download something to play the game - something that will then connect to your centralized, and hosted on the internet server.

There are a couple of approaches to creating a standalone application that essentially just runs your web page.  I've listed a few resources below that might point you in the right direction...

https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier - 
Make any web page a desktop application.  I have not tried this, but at first glance it might be promising.

http://www.qtweb.net/ - QT based open source browser that could perhaps be modified to create a standalone app.

**Footnote**

To reiterate what a few have already stated, this is all dependent on you running an actual web server somewhere that all players connect to.  If you don't want to require that, and the game is a single player game with no need to connect online, then you'll have to make a fully standalone game using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and other file resources.

Here is a collection of different JavaScript game engines that might help if you have to do this:  https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Comment: Thank you, The game is indeed hosted on a server somewhere, and is multiplayer, so the first 2 resources that you send me could be very interested. I will check them out.

Comment: Hey thanks for the clarification.  I think the comments and early downvotes were because people assumed it was not based on a server.  You can ignore my footnote then as I was sort of hedging my bets in case you weren’t doing a server based and multiplayer game.

Comment: I would probably check out the first link to see if that works.  You will find some other solutions though as this need exists outside of the game space.  Try a search for “website as exe” or “website as executable”